# JavaFX how to add ChangeListener to auto scroll TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TableView:

```
@FXML
    private TableView<ThreadInfo> threadsTable;
```

Class ThreadInfo:

```
public class ThreadInfo {

    private StringProperty threadFrom;

    private StringProperty threadDate;

    private StringProperty threadStatus;

    private StringProperty threadTo;

// getters, setters

}
```

I'm trying to add ChangeListener to auto scroll TableView down every time new ThreadInfo object is addedd to my TableView. What I tried:

```
threadsTable.getItems().addListener(
                new ListChangeListener<ThreadInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(
                            javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends ThreadInfo> arg0) {
                        threadsTable.scrollTo(threadsTable.getItems().size());
                    }

                });
```

It has no compilation errors, but doesn't work. I also tried with ChangeListener, but I get: The method addListener(ListChangeListener) in the type ObservableList is not applicable for the arguments (new ChangeListener(){}).

Comment: This works fine for me. Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the problem?

Comment: Thank you, it's a huge project. It's hard to get more then I posted :) It works for me also, but only when I scroll table down manually. Without my action it doesn't work. I also have a second way, but works same for me:

 threadsTable.accessibleRoleProperty().addListener(
    new ChangeListener<Object>() {

     @Override
     public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> arg0,
       Object arg1, Object arg2) {
      threadsTable.scrollTo(threadsTable.getItems().size()-1);
     }
    });

Comment: Don't post your project. Create an example from scratch that replicates the problem.

Comment: I have an answer, posted as answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

I've found my problem. Both methods do the job:

```
threadsTable.getItems().addListener(
                new ListChangeListener<ThreadInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(
                            javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends ThreadInfo> arg0) {
                        threadsTable.scrollTo(threadsTable.getItems().size());
                    }

                });
```

And:

```
threadsTable.accessibleRoleProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<Object>() {

                @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> arg0,
                    Object arg1, Object arg2) {
                threadsTable.scrollTo(threadsTable.getItems().size()-1);
            }
        });
```

The problem is that I'm putting about 1k or more entries to my TableView and it's laggy. On smaller lists it works perfectly.